# Navigate iOS Storyboard ViewControllers from AppDelegate

Tags: iphone, ios, appdelegate

I'm new to iOS development. I have a facebook login app which invokes delegate method in the appdelegate. I did this using .xib views but I need to do it on the storyboard. I have the LoginViewController which has a login button and once user click on it shows FB login and after user logged in it invokes appdelegate method from there I need to navigate to MainViewController. I have tried few ways to do this but its not working. Below is the code that I have tried last. But it's not working or not even give error. Please help me :(((

```
SCAppDelegate* appDelegate = (SCAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
LoginViewController *mvc = (LoginViewController *)appDelegate.window.rootViewController;
MainViewController *lvc2 = [mvc.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainViewController"];
[_navController presentModalViewController:lvc2 animated:YES];
```

Comment: You have a MainViewController called lvc2 and a LoginViewController called mvc... right.

Answer (score 7):

try this one..

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil]; 
MainViewController *lvc = [storyboard   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StoryBoard ID of MainViewController"];
 [(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:lvc animated:NO];
```

Comment: it gives error "Property navigationController not found on object of type AppDelegate". Do I need to add a property with UINavigationController type?

Comment: are you using navigation controller?

Comment: No I don't use navigation controller.

Comment: try adding navigation controller,attach firs view of navigation controller to your rootview...why dont you using it?

Comment: Sorry preetam I'm new to iOS development. My FB login invokes the delegate method from appdelegate when the login got success. So I think I cant just set the navigation controller that's why I thought to do it by coding. Is that possible in my case?

Comment: yes!you can add navigation controller for any kind of application.sorry,I don't the way if not using navigation controller.

Comment: worked for me. I used this when navigating from AppDelegate to another UIViewController.

Comment: worked for me. I used this when navigating from AppDelegate to another UIViewController.